# How to remove full tag from an XML field of CLOB type?

Tags: xml, plsql, clob

I'm trying to remove a node (entity_title) from an XML text in a CLOB field and getting the below error:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET html_key = deletexml(html_key, '//alert/sections/entity_title') 
where id='111';
```

Error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well,what's the content of the XML data then?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like html_key is a CLOB and not an XMLTYPE.  Check out the documentation for [deletexml](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions059.htm#SQLRF06202) and you'll see the function does not work on this datatype.  Maybe checkout the [createXML](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/XMLTYPE.html#GUID-AE968BE1-6551-4DE0-8313-83D2FB7E424E) procedure for XMLTYPE to see if you can convert your existing CLOB.